# How to use WS-Security in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, ws-security

How to create a web service in C# that uses WS-Security for encryption and signatures for both sides (requests and responses)?

Client and server will use certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of the framework you're using, but if it's .NET 2.0 (not using WCF) check out [Web Service Extensions 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en).

That will allow you to implement the WS-Security standards in .NET 2.0 Web Services.

And if you're using WCF, take a look at [this article](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=SecuringWCFService) to get some ideas on how to secure your services using the WS-Security standards.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) - it supports a plethora of WS-* standards - including WS-Security.

WCF is part of .NET 3.0 and up.

Marc